# Strictly inferior strategies for 2-player game

Tags: matrices, game-theory

[image]

[image]

I wanted to check if this is a mistake in the solution. From what I understand, strategy 2 is strictly inferior to strategy 1 for player 2 if ai2>ai1 for all i where aij represents the entry in the ith row and jth column. But here, when i=1, a12=2 and a11=7 and 2 is not more than 2 so how is strategy 2 inferior to strategy 1 for player 2?  Because if strategy 2 is strictly inferior to strategy 1 then we can delete column 2 but it needs to be strictly inferior in the first place which for i=1 it is not.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It should read $a_{i3} < a_{i2}$ for all $i$.

Comment: On another note, let me encourage you to learn to typeset using MathJax: have a look at this [nice tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a mistake in the solution. They probably mean that the second column is dominated by the third, not the first column.